# Azure Virtual Network not showing as an available option when creating new Network Connection

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network

**UPDATE:** After creating a new resource group and a new virtual network that belonged to it, I think this issue might be resolved. It did not show up as an available network at first but after about 15 minutes I refreshed and now it's showing. Maybe I was just too impatient lol.

I am trying to set up a Microsoft Dev Box. This is my first time doing this so I'm just following the [quick start guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dev-box/quickstart-configure-dev-box-service?tabs=AzureADJoin) provided by Microsoft.

I have created a new Virtual Network and didn't change any of the default settings. Now when I go to create a Network Connection, even when I choose the same Resource Group that my network is in, I do not see the option to select it.

[image]

I have tried to create a new resource group and change locations of the virtual network, but neither of those seemed to help.

I haven't had much luck find anybody online with a similar issue. Any advise would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created new resource group and configured Microsoft Dev Box like below:

[image]

Created new virtual network with subnet like below:

[image]

While deploying network connection, selected same resource group and all the virtual networks are displayed like below:

[image]
.
[image]

Sometimes the Azure portal UI won't update or refresh right away. If the Virtual Network doesn't show up in the list of choices, try refreshing the portal page or signing out and back in.

Try creating the network connection from a different location or using a different browser. Sometimes, the Azure portal can have issues with certain browsers or locations.

Answer (score -1):

Deleted everything and restarted and it worked. Create the network before the host pool (Maybe)
Ciao

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).